# Error 500 after upgrade to PHP 5.6

Tags: php, apache

everybody

I'm working on certain project and it worked just fine until the server provider decided to upgrade to PHP 5.6 and now the page is showing error 500.

I've already checked and I found out that this can be caused by few things...

This particular project doesn't use .htaccess file so, I know that's not the problem.

I also read that problem can be somewhere on server so checked the log and this is the message that I get.

> [Fri Dec 04 10:17:47.603342 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12468] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 10.32.109.52:55105] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
>
> [Fri Dec 04 10:17:47.603409 2015] [core:error] [pid 12468] [client 10.32.109.52:55105] End of script output before headers: index.php

Comment: Have you restarted your apache server?

Comment: You may look into php log files. Maybe you have some code that dont want to work on 5.6.

Comment: I have the impression that you've disabled short open tags but your code is using them.

Comment: @AndreFerraz yes, didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You've got a message: `End of script output before headers: index.php`
So check your code in `index.php`. Just try to delete all code from file `index.php` and add this:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This should outputs information about PHP's configuration. If you can see this, so the problem is in your code in `index.php`.

Comment: yes, I've managed to track it down to a single file, but I still don't have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: I guess this error is caused by the **FastCGI** (`FcgidIOTimeout directive`). That is the number of seconds for IO timeout, default is 40 seconds. You can try to solve it putting this into your **.htaccess**: `<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidIOTimeout 300
</IfModule>`